# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling3d_3/MaxPool3D'(op: 'MaxPool3D')with input shapes[?,1,60,60,128]

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am building a keras UNET model for 3D image segmentation.

Image shape  `240, 240, 150`

The input shape is `240, 240, 150, 4, 335` >> training data

The output shape should be `240, 240, 150, 335` >> training labels

I am using Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Conv3DTranspose, and concatenate layers to build the model

I am facing this error during the model building where I am doing upsampling

`ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling3d_3/MaxPool3D' (op: 'MaxPool3D') with input shapes: [?,1,60,60,128].`

I searched for some solutions and found Layers `padding='same'` and `k.set_image_data_format('channels_last')`

with this I faced a new error when doing the concatination after the up sampling

`` ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 30, 30, 18, 256), (None, 30, 30, 19, 256)] ``

I currently looping between those two errors and can't find what is exact issue to solve nether how to solve it

Here is the code where I am building the model

```
def build_unet_model(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    conv1 = create_shared_convolution(inputs, 32, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    block1 = down_convolution(conv1, config.POOL_SIZE)

    conv2 = create_shared_convolution(block1, 64, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    block2 = down_convolution(conv2, config.POOL_SIZE)

    conv3 = create_shared_convolution(block2, 128, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    block3 = down_convolution(conv3, config.POOL_SIZE)

    conv4 = create_shared_convolution(block3, 256, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    block4 = down_convolution(conv4, config.POOL_SIZE)

    conv5 = create_shared_convolution(block4, 512, config.KERNEL_SIZE)  # mid_con
    up1 = concatenate_layers(create_up_convolution(conv5, 256, config.STRIDE_SIZE), conv4)

    conv6 = create_shared_convolution(up1, 256, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    up2 = concatenate_layers(create_up_convolution(conv6, 128, config.STRIDE_SIZE), conv3)

    conv7 = create_shared_convolution(up2, 128, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    up3 = concatenate_layers(create_up_convolution(conv7, 64, config.STRIDE_SIZE), conv2)

    conv8 = create_shared_convolution(up3, 64, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    up4 = concatenate_layers(create_up_convolution(conv8, 32, config.STRIDE_SIZE), conv1)

    conv9 = create_shared_convolution(up4, 32, config.KERNEL_SIZE)
    outputs = create_output_layer(conv9, 4, (1, 1, 1))

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    print(model.summary())
    return model.compile(optimizer=AdaBound(lr=1e-5, final_lr=1), loss=utils.ce_dl_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and those are the 5 functions used in the model building

```
def create_shared_convolution(input_layer, number_of_nets, kernel_size,
                              activation='relu', padding='same',
                              kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(stddev=0.01)):
    conv = Conv3D(number_of_nets, kernel_size, activation=activation, padding=padding,
                  kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(input_layer)

    conv = Conv3D(number_of_nets, kernel_size, activation=activation, padding=padding,
                  kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(conv)
    return conv

def down_convolution(input_layer, pool_size):
    return MaxPooling3D(pool_size=pool_size)(input_layer)


def create_up_convolution(input_layer, number_of_nets, stride_size, padding='same',
                          kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(stddev=0.01)):
    return Conv3DTranspose(number_of_nets, stride_size, strides=stride_size, padding=padding,
                           kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(input_layer)

def concatenate_layers(layer1, layer2):
    return merge.concatenate([layer1, layer2])


def create_output_layer(input_layer, number_of_nets, kernel_size, activation='relu',
                        kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(stddev=0.01)):
    conv = Conv3D(number_of_nets, kernel_size, activation=activation,
                  kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(input_layer)

    return Activation('softmax')(conv)
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci I edited the question, please check

Answer (score 0):

Here are some explanations on both errors.

The first one is due to your features maps being too small in your network. I don't have the detail of your network architecture, but if you apply a lot of maxpooling layers to your input (of shape 240, 240, 150), it might end up with only one value on a dimension (probably something like (N, N, 1)). Adding an other maxpooling on top of this is impossible because you don't have enough value on the dimension to perform it. That's why it raises the negative dimension error.

The second one is probably due to the maxpooling layers. When you apply your first maxpooling, there isn't any issue: the output shape is (120, 120, 75), so upsampling it would give you back the (240, 240, 150). But the next maxpooling (applied to (120, 120, 75)) would produce an output with shape (60, 60, 37) because the last dimension is odd. And upsampling it would give (120, 120, 74). Hence the mismatch. A solution to this is to add `ZeroPadding` layers when the dimension is odd before concatenating them.

Comment: I edit the question and added the model architecture In case this will help more in finding the problem

Comment: I have reduced the number of layers and removed the one with 512 net, I still loping with the same errors but with differant input shape ```ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 120, 120, 76, 64), (None, 120, 120, 77, 64)]```